# How to sort this output 1,10,11..2

Tags: linux, sort

Sometimes I need to add more disk to a database; for that, I need to list the disks to see what disks already exist.

The problem is that the output is always sorted as 1,10,11,12...2,20,21...3 etc.

How can I sort this output the way I want it? A simple `sort` does not work; I've also tried using `sort -t.. -k.. -n`.

Example of what I need to sort:

```
[root@server1 ~]# oracleasm listdisks
DATA1
DATA10
DATA11
DATA12
DATA2
DATA3
DATA4
DATA5
DATA6
DATA7
DATA8
DATA9
FRA1
FRA10
FRA11
FRA2
FRA3
..
OCR1
OCR2
OCR3
....
```

How I'd like to see the output:

```
DATA1
DATA2
DATA3
DATA4
DATA5
DATA6
DATA7
DATA8
DATA9
DATA10
DATA11
DATA12
FRA1
FRA2
FRA3
..
..
FRA10
FRA11
..
OCR1
OCR2
OCR3
....
```

Comment: This is collectively known as "natural sort", and Jeff Atwood wrote about it here: https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your best bet is piping to GNU `sort`, with GNU `sort`'s `--version-sort` option enabled

so that would be `oracleasm listdisks | sort --version-sort`

From the info page

```
--version-sort’
     Sort by version name and number.  It behaves like a standard sort,
     except that each sequence of decimal digits is treated numerically
     as an index/version number.  (*Note Details about version sort::.)
```

On your input it gives me

```
DATA1
DATA2
DATA3
DATA4
DATA5
DATA6
DATA7
DATA8
DATA9
DATA10
DATA11
DATA12
FRA1
FRA2
FRA3
FRA10
FRA11
OCR1
OCR2
OCR3
```

Answer (score 11):

If `sort --version-sort` is not available, split into 2 fields: field 1 = leading non-digits, and field 2 = integer number, and print the fields with TAB between them. Then use `sort` on 2 TAB-delimited fields, then remove the TAB. Connect by pipes to avoid I/O overhead. Here is an example with a minimal slice of the data from the OP, plus a few additional records:

```
echo 1 10 2 11 DATA DATA1 DATA10 DATA11 DATA2 FRA FRA1 FRA10 FRA11 FRA2 | \
    xargs -n1 | \
    perl -lne 'print join "\t", /(\D*)(\d*)/' | \
    sort -k1,1 -k2,2n | \
    perl -pe 's/\t//'
```

Prints:

```
1
10
11
2
DATA
DATA1
DATA2
DATA10
DATA11
FRA
FRA1
FRA2
FRA10
FRA11
```

**DETAILS:**

The perl one-liners use these command line flags:
`-e` : tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-p` : same as `-n`, but also `print` the line at the end of each loop (eliminates explicit `print`).

Within the first one-liner, `\d` is any digit (0-9), and `\D` is any non-digit. Each of these patterns is repeated 0 or more times (using `*`). The two patterns are captured using parentheses and returned as a `LIST` of two fields, which are joined on a TAB and printed.

The second Perl one-liner simply removes the first TAB is finds with nothing (empty string) and prints the line.

To `sort` on 2 fields, these options are used:
`-k1,1` : sort on field 1 ASCIIbetically. Then:
`-k2,2n` : if field 1 is the same, sort on field 2 numerically (`-n` option).
Note that the field number is repeated twice (e.g., `1,1`), to prevent sorting on the rest of the line and limit the sort to just this column number.